# Property 'data' is missing in type 'IData' but required in type 'IData2'

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, express

estoy teniendo un problema con las interfaces en **Typescript**, Tengo dos interfaces en diferentes archivos y cuando los quiero usar al mismo tiempo en un tercer archivo me sale el siguiente error

```
Property 'data' is missing in type 'IData' but required in type 'IData2'.
```

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

**ESTE ES EL TERCER ARCHIVO QUE QUIERO USAR**

```
class UserController {
  public async MyAccount(req: Request, res: Response) {
    // Obtengo el ID del usuario
    const data = req.userId;

    // Creo la intancia de la peticion
    const query = new QueryUser().getQuery("MyAccount");

    // Si existe el Query
    if (query) {
      // Pido los datos con la sentencia
      const response: IData = await query.action(data);

    } /*Si NO extiste el Query*/ else {
      res.status(400).json({
        msg: "Upss! Hubo un error con la peticion ingresada en el servidor",
      });
    }
  }

  public async AddData(req: Request, res: Response) {
    // Obtengo los datos
    const IdUser = req.userId;
    const dataBody = req.body;
    // Configuro los datos a enviar
    const data = {
      id: IdUser,
      data: dataBody,
    };

    // Creo la instancia del Query
    const query = new QueryUser().getQuery("AddData");

    // Si se obtinene el Query
    if (query) {
      // Creo la respuesta
      const response: IData2 = await query.action(data);

    } /*Si NO se obtiene el Query*/ else {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: "Upss! Hubo un problema en el Query!" });
    }
  }
}
```

Ahora las dos interfaces como dije antes las tengo en dos archivos diferentes, las interfaces son las siguientes

**Interface IData**

```
export interface IData {
  error: boolean;
  msg: string;
  data: object;
}
[...]
```

**Interface IData2**

```
export interface IAddData {
  error: boolean;
  msg: string;
}
[...]
```